# How to clean solder paste needles?

Tags: solder-paste, cleaning

I am looking for a good method to clean used solder paste needles immediately after usage. I know they are for one time use, but at this moment I have to clean the needles.

Currently, I clean them in diluent using a thin wire to get all the paste out. **Is there a better way to clean used solder paste needles?**

Comment: Have you tried to intake up a small amount of alcohol and seal tip then return to fridge?  Then release on 1st use.

Comment: No, I haven't. Please corect me if I misunderstood: after usage, I dip the needle (which has solder paste inside) in alchool, seal the tips and refrigerate? So this way, the paste will not harden and I could reuse the needle right away (no cleaning necessary) when I need it?

Comment: That's what I'm thinking .. intake some fluid.... to prevent air leakage to paste for some short period.  Or use compatible liquid flux from a spoon. Then expel when using.

Comment: Thanks! I will try your suggestion. You could post the comment as an answer so I can mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to seal the solder paste from air try to intake a drop of liquid flux into the needle, seal tip then return to fridge.  Then release flux on 1st use.

You might also keep needle in a container permanently mounted to support needle with a small amount of liquid flux to prevent air exposure during use between applications.